# place the "out type " declaration while calling the method

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to use the 'out parameter' within a .NET 4.5.2 application, but I am getting a compile error.

Questions:
In which framework can I compile this? 
What does this called? Inline variable declaration in out method calling?

Could you please provide a reference?

Ref: https://www.dotnetperls.com/parse

> new out syntax: We can place the "out int" keywords directly inside a
>   method call. Older versions of C# do not allow this syntax. But this
>   can reduce the line count of a program.

```
static void Main()
{
    const string value = "345";
    // We can place the "out int" declaration in the method call.
    if (int.TryParse(value, out int result))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This requires [C# version 7](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/09/new-features-in-c-7-0/) that ships with Visual Studio 2017.

The feature is called "Out Variables".

> In C# 7.0 we have added out variables; the ability to declare a
>   variable right at the point where it is passed as an out argument:
>
> ```
> public void PrintCoordinates(Point p) 
> {
>     p.GetCoordinates(out int x, out int y);
>     WriteLine($"({x}, {y})"); }
> }
> ```

Further documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#out-variables).

Comment: It is called: '**inline** out variables'.

Comment: @Odrai The [C# 7 language draft](https://www.ecma-international.org/activities/Languages/C%20sharp%20Standard%20WD3.16.pdf) disagrees. See page 119, 3rd paragraph. Also [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#out-variables).  Not that the exact name is super important.

Comment: Thank you for the links and information. I usually use the keyword 'inline' to clarify the difference between a 'normal'/ 'old' out declaration and the use of an inline one. It's more an abbreviation of the following line:  "You can declare *inline* out values as arguments to the method where they are used.".

Comment: Agreed, it is a good way to clarify the difference between a normal variable receiving the value of the `out` argument, and a variable declared right where it is "returned".